# Show downloaded mp4 inside a view like VStack and play it AVPlayer, SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, avplayer, nsfilemanager

I'm working on the offline downloads section for a video streaming app. Currently, I'm able to download videos and also can see the file path for the downloads as follows:

```
        Button(action: {
            let fileManager = FileManager.default

            do {
                let resourceKeys : [URLResourceKey] = [.creationDateKey, .isDirectoryKey]
                let documentsURL = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
                let enumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: documentsURL,
                                        includingPropertiesForKeys: resourceKeys,
                                                           options: [.skipsHiddenFiles], errorHandler: { (url, error) -> Bool in
                                                                    print("directoryEnumerator error at \(url): ", error)
                                                                    return true
                })!

                for case let fileURL as URL in enumerator {
                    let resourceValues = try fileURL.resourceValues(forKeys: Set(resourceKeys))
                   // print(fileURL.path, resourceValues.creationDate!, resourceValues.isDirectory!)
                    print(fileURL.path)
                    self.array.append(fileURL.path)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }){
            Text("Check downloads")
        }

//response when button is clicked

/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AD90B554-3465-43DD-BAE2-04BC83F850A3/Documents/Bz75srG5nctDCnAWIspM.mp4

/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AD90B554-3465-43DD-BAE2-04BC83F850A3/Documents/GWYgrgDVYaowxeGcOjzp.mp4
```

Since I've renamed the mp4 files using movie ID's (eg: GWYgrgDVYaowxeGcOjzp.mp4) my goal is to use this name to show which videos were downloaded and allow users to play the video. I'm able to do the name processing later on, but how am I able to get the downloaded mp4 files into a view like a VStack? I was thinking of looping through and adding the files into an array but wanted to check if there's a different way. Also, would be great if you could show me how to play a video using the path as the url. I've tried applying suggested methods but ended up with a "NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002" error. Thank you!